# How should I interpolate on a triangle mesh?

Tags: interpolation

I have a triangular mesh (generated from a Lidar point cloud).
On this mesh I do point measurements using two instruments. One records M amplitudes of frequencies in the visible range and the other records N amplitudes of frequencies in the infrared range.

[image]

This picture shows two such measurements: blue visible range and red: infrared range that hits one triangle in the mesh. The other triangles will have from zero to many hits of visible and infrared  but this is not shown.

I need to "combine" these two measurement to make a M+N component vector that will be used to determine the material.

How should I go about interpolating the visible and infrared point measurements on the triangle mesh?

The result may either be interpolated values in the vertices or on the faces, whatever is best.

For visualization with OpenGL I will in the case of values on faces set the values on the vertices to be the average of the values at the adjacent faces.

Comment: without being an expert in spatial interpolation: at which points do you need to know the combined colors? (e.g., at face centers? at vertices?)